# UniqueEntity constraints doesn't show message

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-forms, symfony5

I'm implementing `UniqueEntity` in my App\Entity\User:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="There is already an account with this email")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"username"}, message="There is already an account with this username")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
(...)
```

Constraints work correctly, if I try to duplicate e-mail or username in register form, the form doesn't continue and return me to the form. But when I try to show message with:
`{{ form_errors(registrationForm) }}` it's always null.

```
{{ form_start(registrationForm, {'attr': {'class': 'gap-no read_m span-auto', 'style': 'margin: auto' }}) }}

      {{ form_errors(registrationForm) }}
      
      (...)

      {{ form_row(registrationForm._token) }}
{{ form_end(registrationForm, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

It's wrong? How do I show the message?
Do I have to define something else in the FormType?

Comment: Have you added `unique=true` to your property annotations?

Comment: yes, I have

```

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=191, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Fill username field")
     */
    private $username;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Fill email field")
     */
    private $email;
```

Comment: Have tried to `{% dump(form_errors(registrationForm) %}`

Comment: The error is probably not in the form itself, but in one of the fields of the form (email or username). Try with {{ form_errors(registrationForm.email) }} or {{ form_errors(registrationForm.username) }}. Edit: another choice would be to add error_bubbling true to the FormType (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#error-bubbling)

Comment: I have tried `{% dump(form_errors(registrationForm) %}` and always return `""`.

Comment: Yes, beacuse probably the form doesn't have errors, it's one of the fields which has one. Change it to {% dump(form_errors(registrationForm.email) %} (https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#form-errors-form-view)

Comment: yes, {% dump(form_errors(registrationForm.email) %}  works! thanks!